# adb install system app

Tags: android, adb

I am aware that using adb install command installs an app in the /data/app folder. Also I know the in order to install an app as a system app I need to push it directly to the system. Is it possible to use adb install directly to the /system/priv-app/ on rooted phones?

Answer (score 16):

if I got your question, this should do the work:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push apk-filename-here /system/app/
adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/apk-filename-here
adb reboot
```

See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/76976/how-to-install-app-as-system-app) or [this](https://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/) link for more info.

Comment: In my case I need to use `su` then `mount -o rw,remount /system"` because `remount` command doesn't exists.

Comment: You'll probably need to do adb root before doing remount.

Comment: @林果皞 Do you do this on recovery or while your phone is booted into system?

Comment: On `adb remount` I get: `Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.` I do that but then it doesn't work.

Comment: @Shayan Booted into system,  nothing to do with recovery.

Comment: Can you also say how to undo this?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use adb to directly install app at /system/priv-app/. Even If you copy your .apk, .odex files to this path device can not recognize your app as system app. For this you have to use same certificate with which your system apps are signed.

Comment: You are partially correct. If I place the app in /system/priv-app/ with permissions 644 then next time the phone reboots it will install my app as a system app regardless of being signed with firmware key. I am interested in the adb code to see why I cannot install directly to ADB.

Comment: Adb is works like network protocol, It just moves data to and from android device. Adb uses pm (package manager) internally to install/ uninstall your apps. pm either installs on internal storage or external storage depending on flag in AndroidManifest.xml file or install location specified explicitly during pm. So its pm which is responsible for your app installation not adb.